# free function causing a SIGTRAP

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've a newbie question  regarding freeing memory allocated for an array of struct.
This is the code:

```
typedef struct {
    char code[6];
    char name[31];
    char cname[31];
    int anno;

} cliente;

cliente *readcostumers(char*filename,int * dim) {
    int i;
    cliente *d;
    cliente temp;
    FILE*fp;
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    *dim=0;
    //count the number of lines 
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d", temp.code, temp.name, temp.cname,&(temp.anno))==4)
        (*dim)++;
    rewind(fp);
    //allocate "dim" struct
    int ss = sizeof(cliente);
    d = (cliente*)malloc(ss * (*dim));
    cliente *currCli = d;
    //assign lines to struct
    for(i=0; i<*dim; i++) {
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %d",currCli->code, currCli->name, currCli->cname, &(currCli->anno));
        currCli = currCli + ss;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return d;
}
```

This piece of code basically reads a text file, with any number of lines, formatted with a specific pattern and assign the contents to an array of strcut `cliente`.

This seems to work fine, except when i free the memory previous allocated:

```
int main () {
    int x,i;


    cliente *f = readcostumers("c:/temp/clienti.txt",&x);
    int len = sizeof(cliente);
    for(i=0; i<x; i++) {        
        printf("\n%s %s %s %d",(f + len*i)->code, (f + len*i)->name, 
               (f + len*i)->cname, (f + len*i)->anno);      
    }
    free(f);
}
```

The last statement free(f) causes a SIGTRAP exception, altough the values printed are correct read from file.

The file content is this:

```
A3789 Paolo Rossi 2001
X478D Marcantonio Bianchi 2004
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increment `currCli` in `readcostumers` you should use `1` and in `main` you shouldn't multiply the index with `len`. These are taken care of by the language. These two errors are compensating each other, but in the mean time you are accessing outside the allocated memory and most likely overwriting internal administration of the heap allocation algorithms. Ultimately resulting in a crash in `free`.

Look into the `valgrind` tool as it finds these kind of errors flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing here?

```
 currCli = currCli + ss;
```

You should be incrementing the pointer by 1, not by the size of an element in the array you allocated.  (The language automatically scales pointer additions by the size of the object pointed to.)  This leads to writing outside the allocated area, which in turn leads to corrupted memory, and SIGTRAP or core dump or other similar problems.